# java chart with sql

Tags: java, sql, charts

```
query1 = "SELECT  g.Country , u.Country, u.ID, g.ID From Germany g, Usa u";
dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(conn, query1);
chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("title", "Country", "Numbers", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
```

I need a query that with it I can make the chart, with this query I am only getting one Country and ID, I made every Country in a table so I need all the tables to be in the chart.

Comment: No join condition?

Comment: Do you have one table per country? Poor design. Have one common table for all countries.